# Magento HTML/CSS: table responsive

Tags: html, css, magento

I am trying to create a table using the HTML Code Element within Magento. I have attempted using responsive media types, but it is still stretching off the screen on mobile.

[Magento Responsive Table Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EXHG.png)

```
    <style>
    .table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
    .responsive-table {
        overflow-x: auto;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Variant</th>
                <th>ETA-approval</th>
                <th>Drill diameter</th>
                <th>Min. drill hole depth</th>
                <th>Effect. anchorage depth</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>FIS H 12 x 50 K</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>12 [mm]</td>
                <td>60 [mm]</td>
                <td>50 [mm]</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>FIS H 12 x 85 K</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>12 [mm]</td>
                <td>95 [mm]</td>
                <td>85 [mm]</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>FIS H 16 x 85 K</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>16 [mm]</td>
                <td>95 [mm]</td>
                <td>85 [mm]</td>
            </tr>            
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector .table ist wrong. User the element selector, and remove the ".".

Comment: Apologies as I am new to using Magento (1 week)

I have included a screenshot of the full HTML Code along with the available modules our agency has created for us to use.


[Screenshot](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/16138344?key=b491f1c5f96b0915023fc1eba6fc9136)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
    .table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
    .responsive-table {
        overflow-x: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="responsive-table">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Variant</th>
                <th>ETA-approval</th>
                <th>Drill diameter</th>
                <th>Min. drill hole depth</th>
                <th>Effect. anchorage depth</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>FIS H 12 x 50 K</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>12 [mm]</td>
                <td>60 [mm]</td>
                <td>50 [mm]</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>FIS H 12 x 85 K</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>12 [mm]</td>
                <td>95 [mm]</td>
                <td>85 [mm]</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>FIS H 16 x 85 K</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>16 [mm]</td>
                <td>95 [mm]</td>
                <td>85 [mm]</td>
            </tr>            
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: please explain your code

Comment: The classes(responsive-table & table) was not mentioned in html Code, That's why CSS was not working properly.